# Having trouble exporting a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just trying to make a simple cryptocurrency price ticker and I can't for the life of me figure out how to export a global variable that I set properly.

```
var btcPrice;

setTimeout(function(){
  axios.get("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd").then((response) => {
    btcPrice = response.data.ticker.price;
    console.log(btcPrice);
});
}, 5000);

setInterval(function(){
  console.log(btcPrice);
}, 10000);

exports.price = btcPrice;
```

The setInterval shows the price of bitcoin, as it should. But, when I call it in another file, I get undefined as if it's being exported before the setTimeout finds the value. Any ideas how to export the price? Much appreciated!

Comment: You can't. Export a Promise instead, or better yet: an object that has a function called getPrice that returns a Promise.

Comment: seems this btcPrice should be a Promise

Comment: In your current code, you set `exports.price` only *once*, and that's by the time your module is *first imported*, because that's when node.js will construct the module object. Also, `btcPrice` is in fact local to the module object, and not a global. Unless you export the promise itself, `exports.price` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: I've been sitting here trying to turn that into a promise and I'm completely lost.